# What's actually happens when we try to extract line in file after which `eof` character is present with istream::getline() and std::getline()

Tags: c++, string, file-handling, eof, getline

**roha.txt**

```
I really love to spend time with you.
Let's go for coffee someday.
Enjoy whole day and cherish the memories.
```

**Code-1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main()
{
    char str[100];

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("roha.txt", std::ios::in);

   for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
   {
        std::cout<<bool(fin.getline(str,100) )<<" "<<str<<fin.fail()<<"\n";
   }

}
```

**Output**

```
1 I really love to spend time with you.0
1 Let's go for coffee someday.0
1 Enjoy whole day and cherish the memories.0
0 1
```

**Code-2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main()
{
   string str;

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("roha.txt", std::ios::in);

    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<bool(std::getline(fin,str) )<<" "<<str<<fin.fail()<<"\n";
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
1 I really love to spend time with you.0
1 Let's go for coffee someday.0
1 Enjoy whole day and cherish the memories.0
0 Enjoy whole day and cherish the memories.1
```

I know `C-style char array`, `istream::getline` and `string`, `std::getline` are different. But I want to know what actually happens.

I am guessing that for `string`, `std::getline`, it extracts string for 1st, 2nd and when it tries to extract the 3rd time it sees `eof` so it extracts just before `eof`.

The next time we try to extract it, just encounters `eof` so it didn't extract anything and set `fail-bit`.

`string str` didn't get modified, so when we try to print it, only the string last extracted gets printed.

I don't know if what I’m thinking is right...

Also I can’t make any such case regarding `istream::getline()`, `C-style char array`.

Comment: _"...a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, getline sets eofbit...."_ full info here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `std::ifstream fin; fin.open("roha.txt", std::ios::in);` to `std::ifstream fin("roha.txt", std::ios::in);`. Also, for an `ifstream`, the "i" stands for "input". You don't need to repeat that; `std::ifstream("roha.txt");` is sufficient.

Comment: Note that in `std::cout << f() << g();` there is no requirement on the order in which `f()` and `g()` will be called. The compiler is free to call `g()` first and store the result, then call `f()` and store that result, then do the insertions. In the code in the question, that means that the program could call `fin.fail()` before calling `fin.getline(str, 100)`. (This may have changed in recent standards; I haven't been paying attention to the details recently. Nevertheless, statements like that output statement with implicit order dependencies are hard to read and error prone)

Comment: @PeteBecker first of all thanks. First comment noted and I will take care of that in future. Now Regarding 2nd comment, I deliberately put `fin.fail()` ahead of `fin.getline(str, 100)` so I can check is `getline()` failed or not ?

Comment: Just call `fin.getline(str, 100);` before the output statement. The state of a stream is persistent; if the call to `getline` failed, `bool(fin)` will tell you that. In most cases, you'd be using somthing like `while (fin.getline(str, 100))` to manage a sequence of inputs. But that's not what this code is doing, and there's no need to directly test the return value from calling `getline`.

Comment: @PeteBecker got it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the standard, section 21.3.3.4 inserters and extractors [string.io]:

Clause 6:

> […] After constructing a `sentry` object, if the `sentry` converts to `true`, calls `str.erase()` and then extracts characters from `is` and appends them to `str` […] until any of the following occurs:
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case, the `getline` function calls `is.setstate(ios_base::eofbit))`.
> - […]

Section 29.7.4.1.3 Class `basic_istream::sentry`:

> `explicit sentry(basic_istream<charT, traits>& is, bool noskipws = false);`
> Effects: If `is.good()` is `false`, calls `is.setstate(failbit)`
> […]
> If, after any preparation is completed, `is.good()` is `true`, `ok_ != false` otherwise, `ok_ == false`. During preparation, the constructor may call `setstate(failbit)`
> […]

> `explicit operator bool() const;`
> Returns: `ok_`

So, what is happening with the string version:

1. You extract the last string. This sets eofbit, but not failbit
2. You getline again
3. getline constructs a sentry
4. The sentry checks `is.good()`. This is false because eofbit is set
5. The sentry sets the failbit and sets its member ok_ to false
6. The getline function checks if the sentry is true (operator bool). This is false
7. The getline function returns before clearing your old string

Section 29.7.4.3 Unformatted input functions

Clause 21 (this is about the C-string version):

> In any case, if `n` is greater than zero, it then stores a null character (using `charT()`) into the next successive location of the array

The rest of the wording is similar to the string version. In other words, the C-string version of getline always stores a `'\0'` character, even if it failed. The `std::string` version does not, presumably because it doesn't introduce the same memory safety issues that you have with the C version if you forget to check the failbit.

Comment: your answer is not clear to me. are you saying it is bug ? or anything else ? please answer elaboratively.

Comment: @AbhishekMane Yes, to me it looks like a bug in the standard library implementation that you are using. If I read the standard correctly, the behavior that you describe for istream::getline(char*, size_t) should happen exactly the same for getline(istream, string). Neither version should set failbit if they were able to extract at least one character from the stream.

Comment: see both the overloads of `getline()` are setting `failbit` , when they encounter `eof` and unable to retrieve character, no problem with this working as expected. My point is when I again tries to print `string str` ( `getline(istream, string)` )
it prints what stored it in last time of extraction but when you go with `char str[100]` (`cin.getline(str,n)` )  it prints nothing means empty string so what happening here I am not getting ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane You are right, I misunderstood your question. I have rewritten the answer